# How do I target a specific term or node in a toked?

Tags: tokens

I am developping a site on a dev server, and I am wondering how to create hyperlinks not depending on the server the site is running on.

I have considered usig `href="node/xx"` and `href="term/yy"` but I would like to use the paths generated by pathauto.

But I cannot include the pathauto url as I am certain my client will change titles before I move the site to its final destination, and I might have to regenerate paths to do that.

So I am wondering if there is a way with tokens. Something like `[node:nid:122]` or `[term:tid:122]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [link node](https://www.drupal.org/project/link_node) module is doing this for you. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> Once installed you (or any user who can post) can add an embedded href link to any node using the syntax (where N is a number, and NNN is a node id):
>
> [node:NNN]
>
> Parameters follow the part and are comma separated name="value" pairs:
>
> [node:NNN,title="Original version of the picture"]
>
> [MultiLink](https://www.drupal.org/project/multilink) supports Link Node, so if someone is viewing in another language it gets converted to [node:101] or whatever the correct node is for the translated version automatically.

Comment: Looks good. It doesn't seem to handle terms though. Do you know about another module doing that?

Comment: You can add a feature request for vocabulary terms. IMHO this would be good extension of the module. I'm a Co-maintainer of the module.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the [Pathologic module](http://drupal.org/project/pathologic) and you can link to anything internal (e.g. `<a href="/node/22">` and it will automatically convert the link to the URL alias of node 22 for the current site.